# Linking multiple domains to a server

Tags: dns, nameservers

I have a server that already has a domain, lets say mysite.com but i want to put another site on it with the domain mysite2.com.

So my questions are, how do i set up the nameserver settings.... My first domain i have listed

```
ns1.mysite.com
ns2.mysite.com
```

So would it work if i used:

```
ns1.mysite2.com
ns2.mysite2.com
```

for my new site?

Also, i have to set up "glue records". These are the ns1 and ns2 from the nameserver and provide the ip of my server. So for the mysite2.com would i use ns1.mysite2.com and then the ip would be for example 111.111.111.111/MYSITE2 ? Because the glue record for the first site is just 111.111.111.111.....?

Hope this isn't to confusing, i'm just new to this stuff and want to understand it a bit better and i don't want to mess my original site up in anyway.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure your server is responsible for its own DNS?  When you do a WHOIS for your domain, what name servers are listed?  If you aren't aware of how this stuff works, I suspect that you may not actually have configured the DNS server yourself.

Comment: No i wasn't configured by me. I have a dedicated server with fasthost.

Comment: And you've set up multiple DNS servers in different geographic locations, per the RFC?  Which DNS server software are you using?  Still too many questions for someone to come up with a really useful answer, I think.  Except that @ghoti (below) has given you some basic knowledge that you should be able to leverage to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your DNS records don't have to be within the same domain as the one they host.  If you are running your own DNS servers, they can live inside your primary domain.  But if you're using another DNS provider like zoneedit.com or easydns.com, just use the hostnames they provide.

"Glue records" are the NS pointers that let the root servers find the DNS servers for a particular domain.  For example, there might be:

```
mysite.com    NS    dns1.example.com
mysite.com    NS    dns2.example.com
mysite2.com   NS    dns1.example.com
mysite2.com   NS    dns2.example.com
```

Note that this is entirely different from where your domain's *web site* is served.  For that, you just configure the DNS for each of these domains so that the IP address for the "www" host (and probably the domain itself) points to the same IP ... then you read your web server software's documentation on how to set up "named virtualhosts".

Are you clear on the distinction between DNS hosting and web hosting?  If not, I can go into more detail.